# undefined is no an object( evaluating _this props.navigation.navigate) when i try to navigate after validate

Tags: react-native, validation, navigation

when i trying to navigate after validate to a listdata it show up with erro as my title
? please help i'm newbie in react native. many appreciate from me thank you guys

Btw my code is kinda weird any recommend for me to boost it up? for better performance and easier to understand?

Here all my code below:

/// import code stuff

```
const listData = [
  {
    tenhs: "nguyen quang ha",
    lop: "12b",
    gioitinh: "nam"
  },
  {
    tenhs: "nguyen hoag sn",
    lop: "11b",
    gioitinh: "nam"
  },
  
]

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: {
        username: null,
        email: null,
        password: null,
        confirm_password: null,
      },
      errors: {
        username: null,
        email: null,
        password: null,
        confirm_password: null,
      },
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    if (this.validate()) {
  
      console.log(this.state);

       this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.username = null;
              input.password = null;
              input.email = null;
              input.confirm_password = null;
              return { input };
       });
         this.setState((prevState) => {
              let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
              errors.username = null;
              errors.password = null;
              errors.email = null;
              errors.confirm_password = null;
              return { errors };
       });

       this.props.navigation.navigate('listData');
    }
  }

  /// validate code stuff
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center',backgroundColor: '#00ffff',}}>
        <View style={{padding:5}}>

        ///screen code stuff
       
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={(e)=>{this.handleSubmit(e);}}
        
          style={{
       ///some styles code 
          }}>
          <Text
            style={{
            some styles code
            }}>
            Đăng Ký
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

here is Listdata screen code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import { hScale, vScale, fScale } from "react-native-scales";
import styles from '../one/Styles';

const Listdata = [
    {
      id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba",
      title: "NguyenHoangSon",
    },
    {
      id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63",
      title: "NguyenHoangSon",
    },
    {
      id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72",
      title: "NguyenHoangSon",
    },
  ];
  

  
  export default Listdata;
```

Comment: Can we see where you have setup navigation ? I dont see a navigation container

Comment: `listData` is an array defined in your code and so how will it navigate to `listData` screen.

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan it in the line "  this.props.navigation.navigate('listData');" i think i did it wrong lol

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani hmm so how i do it?

Comment: i mean after validate and submit it will navigate to the arry listData like a list have name in it

Comment: @NguyễnHoàngSơn navigation works on navigator which should be defined in root of your app

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani hmm so how u do that?

Comment: thats a lot of code :) try putting the necessary code to help us read it better and pinpoint the problem

Comment: @AppCity hmm mostly is my validation code i gonna delete it is it okay ?

Comment: Yes, please delete the code which is not relevant to your problem, so can read it better and help you

Comment: @AppCity it good now?

Comment: @NguyễnHoàngSơn , yes much better .

Comment: Post your code for screen - "listData", and how you setup your navigation on the app.js

Comment: @AppCity i just edit can u see the list data now? my navigation is just "   this.props.navigation.navigate('Listdata')"

Comment: @AppCity the navigation in app.js after "      return { errors };
       });" stuff

Comment: Ok, your code is totally wrong for setting up navigation and using the component to display a page. Let me write an answer which can help you better in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things to fix on your code, i will try my best to help you understand how navigation works.

Live Working Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-hugle-ey1yj?file=/src/screens/DetailsScreen.js

1. You have to setup your navigation correctly on App.js
2. You have specify the components which you want to navigate, eg: HomeScreen , DetailsScreen
3. Screens should return a JSX element, not an array.

Below is an simple example to understand how to navigation between screens.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

//Screen 1
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) =>
{

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

//Screen 2
const DetailsScreen = () => 
{
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}


//App.js
const App = () => 
{

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: sr for my late response to your answer btw so hmm i need to make 2 specify screen ?

Comment: Yes, you have to have two different screens and each of them should return a JSX.

Comment: after keep trying do it like 5 hours i completely screwed i i tried to do like u but i cant decide where to put const screen after or before render so i tried both but both failed

Comment: i have edited my answer with live working example. try it and do exactly same as it is in the example. It should work

Comment: ty i gonna try it btw how about render in app.js?

Comment: You do not need render method in Functional Components, you need it only in class based components.